# Dynamic Width Cell in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

[image]

I try to implement labels with `UICollectionView`. But I have to set the widths with dynamic labels length. I try to remove gaps in picture. I share some code. I use Nibs.

Thanks in advance.

```
layoutFCV.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
let filterCV = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: layoutFCV)
```

--

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {       
    if collectionView == filterCollectionView {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "FilterSelectionCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! FilterSelectionCollectionViewCell
        return CGSize(width: cell.title.frame.width , height: self.filterCollectionView.frame.height)
    }  else {
        return CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)
    }
}
```

Comment: Share your UI design how exactly you want?

Comment: I share a pic for what i want

Comment: Just in case, check my answer here with results sample https://stackoverflow.com/a/58081520/2715840

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let text = "Title"
    let width = self.estimatedFrame(text: text, font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)).width
    return CGSize(width: width, height: 50.0)
}

func estimatedFrame(text: String, font: UIFont) -> CGRect {
    let size = CGSize(width: 200, height: 1000) // temporary size
    let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(.usesLineFragmentOrigin)
    return NSString(string: text).boundingRect(with: size,
                                               options: options,
                                               attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font],
                                               context: nil)
}
```

Comment: return CGSize(width: width + 20, height: 50.0) work for me

Comment: Yes, you have to add padding according to you.

Answer (score 1):

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout      collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
     return "String".size(withAttributes: [
       NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
  ])
  }
 }
```

Comment: Add some explenation

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your constraints in `UICollectionViewCell.xib` file has been set correctly. I mean with the growth of `UILabel` in cell, the cell itself should grow as well.

You should explicitly set the title before you get the cell size. So here is your `collectionView(collectionView:, layout:, sizeForItemAt:)` method should be:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {       
    if collectionView == filterCollectionView {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "FilterSelectionCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! FilterSelectionCollectionViewCell
        cell.title.text = "Newest" //this is for the "Newest" cell. Of curse you should set the proper title for each indexPath
        cell.setNeedsLayout()
        cell.layoutIfNeede()
        return CGSize(width: cell.contenView.frame.width , height: cell.contentView.frame.height)
    }  else {
        return CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)
    }
}
```

Comment: cell.layoutIfNeeded() do invisible cells

Comment: You mean it makes the cell invisible? It disappears the cell?

Comment: Yes. If I remove layoutIfNeeded , the cells appears. But width not set with this code.

Comment: It's because your constraint are not properly set in `xib` file. I will update my answer to show how you should set your constraints